# How to load view in phalcon without any other contents

Tags: phalcon, volt

I need to load a part of view in phalcon for returning in ajax call. For this i need to set the view in variables. Now what happening is i am getting all templates including header and footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable rest of the view rendering. Example of exact situation (returning JSON response for AJAX)

```
$viewParams = [
    'param1' => '....',
    'param2' => '....',
];

$response = new \stdClass();
// Render view into a variable
$this->view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_NO_RENDER);
$response->html = $this->view->getRender('yourTemplateDir', 'yourTemplateName', $viewParams, function($view) {
    $view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
});

// Disable view
$this->view->disable();
return $this->response->setJsonContent($response);
```

Comment: Updated my answer to use built in method setJsonContent to avoid using json_encode manually. Thanks to Boris Delev.

Comment: After some of Phalcon versions, this line ```$this->view->disable();``` **can be skipped** when return -> setJsonContent is used.